# Best way to load XACML policy in Distributed PDP Environment

Tags: wso2, xacml, xacml3, xacml2, wso2-identity-server

Hi I am working with `WSO2 Balana XACML` and I found that that sample provided by `wso2` they are loading policy file from `resource folder`. I don't want to load policy from the file system as i want to load it from the DB, or I will give the service URL their my PDP will go check for the policy for the incoming request , or is their any other way please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct. File based policy finder module is sample policy finder module that is shipped with by default. If you are really using Baana,  you may need to use a policy finder that read policies from the database.

Policy finder is an extension point in the Balana, You can write any policy finder module that you wish.  Please find the in-memory policy finder from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/balana/finder/impl/InMemoryPolicyFinderModule.java). You can extend it and write a new policy policy finder for database...

Comment: Hi your Balana works fine for me , but when I am trying to load policies from the URL in the memory and then loading it in to the Document 'DOM' . It is saying '[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.' In my policies I am not using Prolog <xml version =1.0> . How to fix this I am not getting need your suggestion on the same